# Is Alamofire Still Relevant in 2023?

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, urlsession, swift-concurrency

Is there a specific reason for us to continue using the Alamofire dependency in late 2023? Given that we now have URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest) and new Swift concurrency with APIs such as await URLSession.data(for: URLRequest).

I already have my HTTPClient with URLSession data publisher and URLRequest builder for my pets. I haven't had a chance to try await URLSession.data(for: URLRequest) yet. I'm asking this because I'm a newcomer to a project that's just one year old, and the minimum deployment target is iOS 15. However, people on the team are using Alamofire. I don't have any objections to it, but for the sake of clarity, I'd like to confirm whether it's still necessary to use it in today's context.

Thank you for expressing your viewpoint...

Comment: Your question is opinion based, but I do remember that Apple recommend against the use of 3rd party networking frameworks in a WWDC session where they introduced advances in networking. They didn't call out AF explicitly. Their reason is that with 3rd party frameworks you not be able to take advantage of improvements  they Apple make immediately; you need to wait for the framework to add support for them.

Comment: @Paulw11 source for that? I can imagine they said something like that about AFNetworking back when they introduced URLSession, since AFNetworking wrapped URLConnection at that time, but I don't recall anything like that in the last 10 years. Aside from the new delegate methods, Alamofire takes advantage of any improvements to URLSession automatically.

Comment: kefir, Alamofire has explicit support for both [Swift concurrency](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-swift-concurrency) and [Combine](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-combine). So, it is not a question of Alamofire *versus* Concurrency and/or Combine, but rather rather whether or not you want to use it *with* Concurrency and/or Combine.

Comment: The decision process with Alamofire is like any other third party dependency, namely, the balancing the advantages/features offered versus the costs/overhead. IMHO, for developers new to networking protocols, I heartily recommend Alamofire. For those very familiar with the idiosyncratic little details of networking protocols, the case is less compelling. Concurrency and/or Combine really do not factor into that calculus at all.

Comment: “people on the team are using Alamofire” … If the team is already using Alamofire, then you almost certainly should do so, as well. Having different team members follow different paradigms/patterns is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: @Rob If you were to start a project from scratch, would you include Alamofire, or do you have your own client with retries and authorization token refreshing?

Comment: If I were you, I would probably run with Alamofire. It's robust, actively maintained, widely adopted, and keeps you out of the weeds of networking code.

Comment: I like the retry policy (even if now with async/await, it's easier to write yourself in URLSession), but the errors management (be it "URLSession error", or HTTP error is nice), and I love the interceptors (that I used for cURL logs to pass the command to back-end dev if needed to reproduce and help fixing). Everything can be "redone" indeed, it's up to you, your time, your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use dependencies so you don't have to write (and test, hopefully!) the code yourself. How valuable that is depends on the features you're writing, how much time you want to spend writing them, and the reliability you want in the end. You use Alamofire so you don't have to write your own `HTTPClient` or data publisher and can then take advantage of things like automatic retry.

Few, if any dependencies, are really "necessary".

Comment: @John Shier Thanks for answer. If you were to start a project from scratch, would you include Alamofire, or do you have your own client with retries and authorization token refreshing?

Comment: @kefir – Jon might be a little biased as a key Alamofire contributor and a board member. Lol.

Comment: @Rob is right! I always use Alamofire, not only because it *is* the network stack I wrote myself, but because it's (I think) good, quality software that I don't have to worry about. Regardless, I tried to make this answer generally applicable to all dependencies.